# Hide Cell when the condition is met

Tags: swift, uitableview

Hello StackOverflowers!

I am trying to hide cells when condition is met - in this case when the user survey comment is empty. The data is loaded from Firebase This is what I have tried so far:  hiding the cell as well as selecting it. Then follow with heightForRow for selectedRows. But it's not working. Please help! Thank you~~~

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return comment.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CommentsTableCell", for: indexPath) as! CommentsCell
    let surveyCommentList = self.comment[indexPath.row]
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none
    if surveyCommentList.surveyComment == "" {
        cell.isHidden = true
        cell.isSelected = true
    } else {
        cell.surveyCommentText.text = surveyCommentList.surveyComment
    }
    return cell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows, selectedRows.contains(indexPath) {
        return 0
    } else {
        return 50
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct implementation :

```
 // Define a new filtered array from your comments that filters empty Comments
 let filteredComments = comment.filter({!$0.surveyComment.isEmpty)

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filteredComments.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CommentsTableCell", for: indexPath) as! CommentsCell
    let surveyCommentList = self.filteredComments[indexPath.row]
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none
    cell.surveyCommentText.text = surveyCommentList.surveyComment
    }
    return cell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
}
```

Comment: You forgot the surveyComment :)  `comment.filter { !$0.surveyComment.isEmpty }`
And in the heightForRowAt the return has to be only 50

Comment: @FrancescoDeliro Yes Thanks!, I am going to edit that, but he gets the idea anyway :)

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks guys!

Comment: @Anna1999 Your welcome, oh, you are a she, I wrote he by mistake! 